# Survey Questions for Data Mining Project JUSTNN

Tags: survey

I am having a really hard time in doing my Data Mining project. We've decided on a topic that ***WHAT DO HIGH-SCHOOL GRADUATE STUDENTS LOOK FOR WHEN JOINING ANY UNIVERSITY?***
Factors like cost, convenience, major etc., These can be considered as an attributes for our case. & We are gonna give 3 choices of University in our city!

Problem that I am having is what questions should my survey contains that helps me in acheiving my goal?? :-/ Once Im done with the survey, How can I analyze the survey using the JUSTNN software...

I'll be using [JUSTNN software](http://www.justnn.com/) for prediction purposes & results.. Really in need of suggestions or help..

Answer (score 2):

I would consider asking questions similar to the data collected in the IPEDS surveys by the US Department of Education. Each year, every accredited university/college and trade school fills this survey out. It includes a large number of questions, including: tuition, books, housing on/off campus, degrees offered, size of freshman class, student population by ethnicity, etc.

You can download standard or customized tables from the US Dept of Ed here:
http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/

I also have a number of these tables converted into CSV format, which anyone is free to use:
http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.1/US%20Education/IPEDS/

Comment: Oh Thank-you very much! So, u saying I don't need to do a survey instead take this data for my project?

Comment: These surveys are filled in by the Universities (not the students). But they likely reflect the interests of the students and should help you pick a "good" set of survey questions for students.